# Class and module scope in rails helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, helper

I'm trying to write a rails app that creates an object in the controller based on a helper module, which is written below:

```
module StockPricesHelper
    require 'net/http'
    class Stock
        attr_accessor(:data)
        def initialize(stock)
            @url = "http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=#{stock}&f=sb2b3jk"
        end
        def download_data
            @data = NET::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(@url)).body
        end
        def clean_string
            @data = @data.strip
        end
        def db_format
            1
        end
    end
end
```

I get an error `uninitialized constant StockPricesHelper::Stock::NET` from the rails server.

1. Am I correctly putting this in a helper module?
2. What am I doing wrong? I think I'm off on the scope but I don't know where.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have misspelled the "NET" module. It is **`Net`**. (Ruby is case sensitive)

Rails helpers are intended to be *view* helpers, i.e. aid in generating HTML. 
It looks like you are performing something which would be better placed in a controller or background job.

Comment: thank you. someday i'll be a vastly confident rails user and think to look for spelling errors rather than major flaws in my understanding of oop :P

Comment: That feeling is quite normal when learning a new language or framework :)